# TextEdit Version 1.18 (Ventura) changed behaviour from 1.17 (Monterey)

Tags: monterey, text, textedit, ventura

In TextEdit Version 1.17 (Monterey) I can take a text list and drag/select an item all the way across into the white space at the end of the line. If I hit delete, the selected characters plus the white space are deleted and the items underneath then move up a line.

In TextEdit Version 1.18 (392) (Ventura) dragging across a list item into white space selects the characters, the white space AND the list item below, unless I’m missing something. I can’t seem to select just the characters plus the white space (ie the whole line and just the whole line.)

Both versions are set to Wrap to Window in Rich Text Format and all other settings are identical. Interestingly if I set the 1.18 version to Wrap to Page I can achieve the desired behaviour but I'd prefer to work in Wrap to Window if possible. Any ideas?